# WooCommerce doesn't show UK countries in the shipping options

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

For some reasons, when I’m on the front-end, in the cart page, I cannot find any countries in the UK for the shipping estimation.
No England, no Ireland, etc.
But I got pretty much every other countries in the world. I haven’t put anywhere that I don’t want to ship to UK.

The selling point is set to “Sell to all countries”.

Other than that, is there any reason this can happen?
I am using a plugin called “WooCommerce Shipping Per Product v2”, to handle shipping pricing per products, but the only thing I do is setting the price per regions, and I cannot modify regions in the system so, this shouldn’t be an issue.

I know there's the WooCommerce plugin forum, but nobody is responding to my question there. I would really appreciate if someone here could help me with that issue.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: In the choice of the country, you don't see "United Kingdom ?"

Comment: Exactly. I open the dropdown menu to select the country, and it seems that all countries are there, except the ones from the UK. All countries in the world. Bangladesh, Canada, United States, Australia, and so on...but no UK countries. Any idea what can cause that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to find England specifically in their list. The UK treats several areas as separate countries, and other regions can only be separated by postal code.

- United Kingdom
- Republic of Ireland
- Jersey
- Guernsey
- Isle of Man

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/i18n/countries.php

I should also mention that the "Sell to countries..." field controls the Billing side of the form. There is still an option of countries you "Ship to", and this alters the countries in the Shipping form (or the Billing form if you are shipping to the billing address). Make sure you haven't narrowed down that list without United Kingdom being list.

And lastly, it is possible to modify the countries and regions through filters. Go to the General tab of your WooCommerce settings page and try to modify the Sell to or Ship to settings. If you cannot find the UK in that list either, then it's been removed through its filter.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! I didn't know that. Thanks for your help :)